# How to capture all the HTTP requests of a website using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, testing, automated-tests, sh

As a web application tester I need to verify the http requests(seen in the net tab of the firebug when you hit a site in firefox) for my web site.

Is there a way to capture the http requests/network calls in shell scripting?

I have solution to do it in Java. We can use browsermob proxy.

But please help me how to do in shell scripting.

Comment: More information will help us to help you. For example: What is your webserver? (if is apache you can use mod_status)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) What you can do is run a script to capture requests going to your server and then verify them within [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Which provides a more user friendly output than the raw TCP dumps. If your want to listen to everything on port 80 (HTTP) you can run the following command:

```
sudo tcpdump -s 0 -X 'tcp dst port 80' -w capture.pcap
```

At a later time you can copy the `capture.pcap` file which onto a machine running Wireshark. Load it, and browser through the TCP dumps to make sure the expected traffic occured.